# How to delete from webapp2 extras appengine auth models Unique?

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2

I [reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14912750/solved-how-to-delete-from-webapp2-extras-appengine-auth-models-unique) how to delete from webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models.Unique

This solution worked with:

`Unique.delete_multi( map(lambda s: 'User.auth_id:' + s,user.auth_ids))`

Problem is that there is a second record.  The following statement has no effect:

`Unique.delete_multi( map(lambda s: 'User.email:' + s,user.email))`

No error in the log.  Nothing happens.

The record I'm trying to delete has the value in field "Key Name" in Unique is "User.email:test@example.com"
When the user is created, the unique_properties is as follows:

```
unique_properties = ['email']
```

Thinking it was some kind of lock, I tried logging user out first, then deleting user (saved user.email to a temp var).  No dice.

Answer (score 1):

solution was found in using delete_multi differently for auth_ids and email:

for user.email (note in OP the way email was created):

```
unique_email = ['User.email:%s' % user.email]
Unique.delete_multi(unique_email)
```

for user.auth_ids:

```
Unique.delete_multi( map(lambda s: 'User.auth_id:' + s,user.auth_ids))
```