# GQL query for webapp2 Unique logins

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2, gql, gqlquery

I want to use GQL to find specific entries in Google App Engine Datastore.

The entities that I want locate are webapp2 unique user records. I have tried structuring the query with keys, strings, etc, without success.

---

**EDIT:** 
the entities' model is [webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models.Unique](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/appengine/auth/models.html#webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models.Unique)

Unique entities are inserted using attributes of the [webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models.User](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/appengine/auth/models.html#webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models.User) class. It has an auth_id property that stores login information ("own" for custom logins, "google" or "yahoo" etc for google or yahoo usernames), properties that must be unique for each User and custom properties.

So, if a User's email and social security number must be unique, the corresponding entries for auth_id, email and social security number will be created in Unique (provided that the insertion doesn't result in duplicate entities). That will result in entities:

```
name=User.auth_id:own:someusername@example.com
name=User.social_security_number:1234567890
name=User.email:someusername@example.com
```

---

Some of my attempts include:

```
SELECT * FROM Unique where __key__ = KEY('name',User.auth_id:own:someusername@example.com)
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Unique where name = 'User.auth_id:own:someusername@example.com'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Unique where 'name=User.auth_id:own:' = 'someusername@example.com'
```

These queries are either syntactically invalid or have invalid parameters. I have obviously reviewed Google's official documentation but cannot find a way to write this one.

---

**EDIT:**
There is a way to retrieve all the unique records in [python using a method of Unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14912750/solved-how-to-delete-from-webapp2-extras-appengine-auth-models-unique). What I'm looking for is a GQL query.

---

Comment: Your question is confusing. Can you post the code for the model-class?

Comment: I added an explanation for the model.